# IKE version and encryption for GCP VPN

Tags: google-compute-engine, vpn

I need to migrate an existing VPN peer to GCP, my current parameters are:

```
transform: esp-3des esp-sha-hmac no compression, settings ={L2L, Tunnel, IKEv1, }
```

I read in GCP documentation that the GCP VPN doesn't support 3des with IKEv1 (https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers)

What is the good settings for IKEv2?

Comment: If you're setting this up for a whole team or company, you'll get a better answer on serverfault.com - see https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ikev2. If you're asking just for yourself, try superuser.com. You can re-use your stackoverflow account on both of those.

Answer (score 0):

Any device or services that support IKE ciphers for IKE version 1 or 2 [1] should be compatible with Cloud VPN. Each vendor has its own specific instructions for VPN configuration, however, GCP VPN interoperability guides provides Google-tested interoperability guides and vendor-specific notes for peer devices or services that you can use to connect to Cloud VPN.

[1]Supported IKE ciphers: https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers

[2] VPN interoperability guides: https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/interop-guides